# Laravel Raw Query giving error in join with raw statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have two tables users and db_ips and I need to compare users lattitude and longitude with two three decimal points value with db_ips table column lat lon, For this I write query in laravel.

**Query**

```
$users = \DB::table('users')
         ->select("id", "latitude", "longitude")
         ->Join('IPAddress AS IP', \DB::raw('ROUND(IP.lat,3)'), '=', \DB::raw('ROUND(users.latitude,3)'))
         ->where('users.login_tries', "=", 0)
         ->where('users.latitude', "<>", "")
         ->whereNotNull('users.latitude')
         ->orderBy("id", "ASC")->limit(100)->get();
return !$users->isEmpty() ? $users : [];
```

For two three decimal comparison I use ROUND medthod in join but when I run the query I get following error instead of results

**Error**

> Too few arguments to function
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(), 1      passed in
>   /home/rizwan/php/fayvo/archive/app/Console/Commands/SyncUserLocat
>   ion.php on line 139 and at least 2 expected

I also try to raw query but unknow column_name in field_list error received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> join(string $table, string $first, string|null $operator = null, string|null $second = null, string $type = 'inner', bool $where = false)

According to `join` API, it need at least 2 parameters, so change your code like this:

```php
->Join('IPAddress AS IP', \DB::raw('ROUND(IP.lat,3)'), '=', \DB::raw('ROUND(users.latitude,3)'))
```

Comment: Now getting this error
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IP.lat' in 'field l  
  ist' "

Comment: @RizwanSaleem `lat` is the column of `IPAddress`?

Comment: yes lat is the column of IPAddress

Comment: @RizwanSaleem it works fine to me, have u add \DB::raw() to`ROUND(IP.lat,3)`?

Comment: @TasaiKog are you talking about DB Facades ?

Comment: @RizwanSaleem yes. just like my answer.Or u can post the code u changed

Comment: I have updated the quetion with your modifications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212755/discussion-between-rizwan-saleem-and-tsaikoga).